# How to filter a data source (AWS AMI) based on a list of tags

Tags: tags, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create an **aws_ami** data source that fetches the latest AMI based on a few tags.

The catch is that I want to do it with a map of tags and their values, not by defining filters for each specific tag in the data source.

Example:

**module-vars.tf**

```
variable "filter-tags" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    "java_vendor" = "oracle"
  }
}
```

**module.tf**

```
data "aws_ami" "aws-ami" {
  most_recent = true
  owners = ["self"]

  // Filter code here
  // e.g. FICTIONAL CODE, DON'T USE
  filter {
    name = "tags:${var.filter-tags}"
  }
}
```

So obviously this **filter-tags** variable should be able to change and the filtered AMI should have all the tags matching.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting the argument `tags = var.filter-tags` ?

Comment: That just gives me the latest AMI, I don't think it takes the tags into account

Comment: Found a way to do it with dynamic blocks

Comment: isn't the intent to get the latest ami is you have `most_recent = true` set? What is the `tags` argument used for if it doesn't take the tags into account ?

Comment: The tags argument is not even part of the documentation for aws_ami data source. I guess it may be inherited from somewhere and that's why terraform accepts it there, but it has no function, or the function is not related to the filtration of the data source

Comment: Strange because it's given as an example [on configuring data sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html) and is also documented on the [data source aws_ami](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ami.html#tags). Perhaps this is a bug that should be opened with the provider?

Answer (score 3):

Found a way to do it with [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks)

```
variable "filter-tags" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    "java_vendor" = "oracle"
  }
}

data "aws_ami" "aws-ami" {
  most_recent = true
  owners      = ["self"]

  dynamic "filter" {
    for_each = var.filter-tags
    iterator = tag

    content {
      name   = "tag:${tag.key}"
      values = ["${tag.value}"]
    }
  }
}
```